# Accessing the Spotify API data (i.e. tokens) from redirect_uri via nodejs then redirect to angular app

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, spotify

Hi I'm creating a web application using node.JS and AngularJS. I'm fairly new to both technologies.

This is my app setup:

**node.JS + mongoDB REST API** - This will handle all server side requests as well as communicate to Spotify (*http://localhost:3000*)

**AngularJS** - For the app itself (*http://localhost:8080*)

Spotify has recently made it's [**Spotify Web API public**](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/). I'm trying to retrieve the access token (and refresh token) so I can make API calls to them. I was able to get the access_token & refresh_token, however, since I'm coming from *http://localhost:8080/test* to *http://localhost:3000/spotifyapi/login* to initialize the auth then to *http://localhost:3000/spotifyapi/callback* to receive the tokens.

If you could please help/guide me on how to retrieve the tokens/make api calls then pass it back to my AngularJS app, it would be greatly appreciated.

Below are my codes:

*I'm using grunt to compile all JS into one file  in my Angular app*

**NODE.JS API** (*http://localhost:3000/spotifyapi*)

*spotify.js*

```
var SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');
var request = require('request');
var querystring = require('querystring');

var client_id = config.spotify.client_id,
 client_secret = config.spotify.client_secret,
 redirect_uri = config.spotify.redirect_uri;

var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
 client_id: client_id,
 redirect_uri: redirect_uri
});

exports.login = function(req, res) {
 var scope = 'user-read-private playlist-read playlist-read-private',
    state = 'mixr-test';

res.redirect('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?' +
    querystring.stringify({
        response_type: 'code',
        client_id: client_id,
        scope: scope,
        redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
        state: state
    }));
};

exports.callback = function(req, res) {
var code = req.query.code;
var authOptions = {
    url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
    form: {
        code: code,
        redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        client_id: client_id,
        client_secret: client_secret
    },
    json: true
};

request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var access_token = body.access_token,
            refresh_token = body.refresh_token;

        var options = {
            url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
            },
            json: true
        };

        // res.send(options);

        res.redirect('http://localhost:8080/#/test#' +
            querystring.stringify({
                access_token: access_token,
                refresh_token: refresh_token
            }));
    }

    res.send({
        access_token: access_token,
        refresh_token: refresh_token
    });
});
};

exports.refreshToken = function(req, res) {
var refresh_token = req.query.refresh_token;

var authOptions = {
    url: 'https:/accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer(client_id + ':' +
            client_secret).toString('base64'))
    },
    form: {
        grant_type: 'refresh_token',
        refresh_token: refresh_token
    },
    json: true
};

request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        var access_token = body.access_token;
        res.send({
            'access_token': access_token
        });
    }
});
};
```

*routeMap.js*

```
module.exports = [
  ['/spotifyapi', 'spotify#index', 'get'],
  ['/spotifyapi/login', 'spotify#login', 'get'],
  ['/spotifyapi/callback', 'spotify#callback', 'get'],
  ['/spotifyapi/refreshToken', 'spotify#refreshToken', 'get'],
];
```

**AngularJS app** (*http://localhost:8080/test*)

*SpotifyService.js*

```
app.factory('SpotifyService', function($http) {

var apibaseUrl = "http://localhost:3000";

 return {
    login: function(config) {
        return $http.get(apibaseUrl + '/spotifyapi/login');
    },
    callback: function(access_token, refresh_token) {
        return $http.get(apibaseUrl + '/spotifyapi/callback', {access_token:access_token, refresh_token:refresh_token});
    },
    refresh: function(refresh_token) {
        return $http.get(apibaseUrl + '/spotifyapi/refreshToken', {access_token: access_token, refresh_token: refresh_token});
    },
    getUsers: function(){
        return http.get(apibaseUrl + '/users');
    }
 };
});
```

*SpotifyCtrl.js*

```
app.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', 'SpotifyService', function($scope, SpotifyService) {

    $scope.access_token = '';
    $scope.refresh_token = '';

    var getLogin = function() { 
        SpotifyService.login().success(function(data){
            SpotifyService.callback(access_token, refresh_token).success(function(data){
                $scope.access_token = data.access_token;
                $scope.refresh_token = data.refresh_token;
            }).error(function(data){
                console.log("error!" + data);
            });
        }).error(function(data){
            console.log("error!" + data);
        });
    };
 }
]);
```

*spotify.jade*

```
block content
  div#container(ng-controller="SpotifyCtrl")
    a(href="http://localhost:3000/spotifyapi/login" class="btn btn-large") Login via Spotify
      p {{ access_token }}
      p {{ refresh_token }}
```

I'm able to go to Spotify's login page -> authenticate. My redirect_uri is *http://localhost:3000/spotifyapi/callback*. When authentication is finished, I'm able to get my access_token and refresh_token but I'm still on my node.JS API server and I can't get any value from my Angular Service to pass to my view. How do I redirect from my redirect_uri back to my Angular app and be able to retrieve the access and refresh tokens via my Angular services?

I apologize for this lengthy post, I'm just in a road block right now on how to complete this module.

**THANK YOU IN ADVANCE!**

Comment: May I humbly suggest that you only use one webserver instead of two? I believe this would make things a lot simpler for you going forward.

Comment: You should be able to read the access token and refresh token that you are passing as a uri fragment from AngularJS. Alternatively, you can also write the values in a cookie and read them from AngularJS. Moreover, if your Angular app is running on http://localhost:8080/test, shouldn't you redirect to http://localhost:8080/test#<something> when you get the token, instead of http://localhost:8080/#/test#<something> ?